# How can I pass the string to mdates.WeekdayLocator()

Tags: python-3.x

If I pass value "TUESDAY" directly to the WeekdayLocator as follows:

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(TUESDAY))
```

The result I get is correct. Now, when I try to pass the value from given code below:

```
day = calendar.day_name[date.today().weekday()].upper()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.grid(True)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
lns1 = ax1.plot(date, y, marker='o')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(day))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%b %d'))
plt.show()
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\py\weekly.py", line 53, in <module>
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(day))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 1250, in __init__
    interval=interval, **self.hms0d)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 721, in __init__
    self._rrule = rrule(**self._construct)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dateutil\rrule.py", line 591, in __init__
    elif not wday.n or freq > MONTHLY:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Can anybody please help me how to pass the value I get in "day" mdates.WeekdayLocator()

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace and possibly your source code?

Comment: I have updated the full traceback.

Comment: according to error, you are assinging a string value to `mdates` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes i am getting string value in day. How can I pass it to mdates?